# Back up snapshots without being admin

Tags: files, backup, snapshot

I would like to make a back up/snapshot of a folder where I have built various programs (~4.1 GB in size). The idea is to be able to **quickly** restore everything in this path to it's original state in case something happened to the drive where it resides.

One limitation I have is that I do not have access to the hardware nor sys rights to this machine (not sure if I may need them when *restoring* things)

Can I preserve every file, permission, timestamp, symbolic link, etc. in a tar file? Most importantly, would that be enough to later restore every single file and program to a working state?

If tar is not an adequate for this task, what are my alternatives? Are there any other  (free) command line tools that are better for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar` should be able to handle all of your requirements, but you probably want to use the options `--atime-preserve` and `--preserve-permissions`.

I have been using [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) for (incremental) backups over the network. It can be used locally as well. `rdiff-backup` does preserve links and timestamps, but I have not checked specifically on access time restore etc.